# Quick editing of taxonomy tags on a node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am using Drupal 7 [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum). I have added a taxonomy field so that posts can be tagged with keywords (like in this forum).

Currently if an editor responds to a customer post, the process for doing so is a bit cumbersome:

1. edit the customer post to add tags.
2. once this is done, then reply to the post.

I need to make the process of adding or modifying tags easier.  Perhaps with a button next to the tags so they can be edited in-place.

How can I edit taxonomy fields & reply to posts in the same form?

Comment: I've found a couple of possible solutions -  [Quick edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit), which seems to have a large number of dependencies and JS requirements, and [Field API Pane Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/fape), which looks like it is much more widely used, but it did have an alarming looking security issue recently. I'll have a play with that one and see if it can do what I need.